# How to query based on a field in a referenced document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two MongoDB collections. First is `Products`, and the seconds is `Users`. The product documents has a field `ownerId` which refers to the users collection and the user has a Boolean field `isActive`.

What I want to do is to find all the products where their users are active using Mongoose method `collection.find()`. I don't know if i can do that querying only the products collection . Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only store user's reference in the products documents, you would have to use `aggregate` query:

- `$lookup` - to populate **owner** property with the actual user data.
- `$match` - to filter only the documents where owner's **isActive** property is equal to **true**.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "ownerId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "owner"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "owner.isActive": true
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4V6M6y6fxea)